# How does the jQuery length property work in this line of code?

Tags: jquery

quick question. 
I have a form and long story short, i got it to work using this block of code:

```
.on('click', '.modalAddToBagButton', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $form = $(this).closest("#dialog-addToBag").find('form');
            if( $( ".es-value.selected" ).length ) {
                $form.submit();
            } else {
                $("#errormessage").show();
                $("#error-border").addClass("error-border");
            }
        });
```

However, I am not 100% clear on how the .length is working here. Could someone please explain this to me? I'm learning and it would help me in the future to fully understand. Thank you!

Comment: `0` is falsy. This means that `if (0)`, or `if (anything that evaluates to 0)` will always return **`false`**.  `if ($(element).length)` is simply checking *"If (there are any `.es-value.selected` elements)"*

Comment: [jQuery length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) and [JavaScript *truthy* values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: And `jQuery(selector)` returns an array like object that has length...which is zero if no matching elements exist

Comment: @TylerRoper so does that mean my if statement is true, because the length is greater than 0?

Comment: Correct. Your statement will evaluate to `true` as long as the selector `$( ".es-value.selected" )` finds at least one element. It looks like this code in particular is just looking to make sure that there is at least one selection. If so, submit the form. Otherwise, there are no `es-value` items selected, show an error message.